# math kernel library function produce different result on different machine

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I'm implementing an eigen-decomposition method by making use of math kernel library in fortran.

Inside the method, I first try to apply zgehrd to convert the input matrix into a upper Hessenberg form.

During the debug, however, I found given the same input matrix, the method zgehrd produces different results on different computers. Some computers are in windows 10 while some are still in windows 7.

To further test whether this problem is system dependent, I installed a windows 10 (Pro 64 bit) VM machine on a windows 10 (Home 64 bit) computer. It turns out the results are still different slightly in this case.

Since the eigen-decomposition method will be recursively called by an optimizer, the slight differences will accumulate. I've tried the solution by enforcing the Conditional Numerical Reproducibility in fortran, yet it does not help. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I just assume you are referring to intel MKL? It would be helpful for people to understand your question if you can provide more information. My guess it might be related with https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/understanding-cpu-optimized-code-used-in-intel-ipp, are your CPUs also the same? Intel MKL might use CPU dispatch, and different CPU may execute different code path.

Comment: @KL-Yang The interesting thing is that I compared the result in a virtual machine on a computer. The virtual machine (VM) shares the same CPU as the physical computer and therefore the dispatch policy should be the same? Yet the result from VM still differs

Comment: The dispatch is based on CPUID, may not necessarily be the same as host. I am just guessing, how about the same VM image on two different machines, will it give the same result?

Comment: @KL-Yang I run the code on the same image on the other host. The code produce the different result on the image system. However.the result is the same as it produce on both hosts

Comment: OK, I am a little big confused, let's say you have two host A, and B, and one VM image. You program produce different result on A and B, but produce the same result in A-VM and B-VM?

Comment: @KL-Yang I'm sorry to make you confused. The situation is like this. I have two hosts, A and B. The code produce exactly the same result on A and B. However, I know the code will produce different result on some other hosts. To simulate this difference, I installed a VM image on host A. On this image, the code produce a different result. Then I copy the VM image to host B. This time the code produce the same result as it does when it runs directly on host A and host B.  (The image is not exactly the same. Since on host A I use virtual box but on host B, I use VMware)

Comment: For what I know, there is only 3 possibilities (assume same binary used in the test), 1 is dynamic linked library is different, 2 is same library but CPU dispatch different code path, 3 is something that I don't know :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see bit-to-bit output results with Intel MKL on different machines, please call MKL_VERBOSE mode ( set/export environment variables  MKL_VERBOSE=1 ) first and check the lowest reported code branch. Example: 
running the MKL code on AVX and AVX-512 based systems we will see the following messages:
`MKL_VERBOSE Intel(R) MKL 2019.0 Update 4 Product build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (**Intel(R) AVX**) enabled processors, Lnx 2.80GHz intel_thread`

and on SkyLake system:
`MKL_VERBOSE Intel(R) MKL 2019.0 Update 4 Product build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions 512 (**Intel(R) AVX-512**) enabled processors, Lnx 2.20GHz intel_thread`

The next steps: 
Calling the MKL’s bitwise reproducibility features by setting the environment variables: set/export MKL_CBWR=AVX
Then MKL guarantees that you will see the same outputs on AVX and AVX-512 based systems in the case of **the same #of threads and the same OS.**